# c++ logging from parallelized loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openmp

I have a parallel for loop and ONCE for looping I'd like to log some details.

```cpp
first_iteration = true;

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(runtime) 
for (int j = 0; j < items.size(); j++) {

    if (first_iteration) {
        FILE_LOG(logINFO) << "blablabla";
        first_iteration = false;
    }

    // do something
}
```

But it is always logged several times (probably number of thread times). And I have a suspicion that time to time it throws a segfault.
I've read a possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55881674/8703313) with temp variable and `#pragma omp atomic read` and `write`. But it doesn't seem to work with Visual Studio 19 (c++std14):

> error C3005: 'read': unexpected token encountered on OpenMP 'atomic' directive`.

I need it work also in g++ 11.3.0.

Comment: Checking the value of `first_iteration` and then setting it is not atomic. Several threads can observe `first_iteration == true` before setting it to `false`. Not sure about specific OpenMP solutions, and it might not be the most efficient way, but you can always protect this code piece (checking, logging and setting) with a mutex.

Comment: that's clear, but how to make it atomic? `#pragma omp atomic read` and `write` doesn't seem to work with MSVC...

Comment: can you use a `std::atomic<bool>`?

Comment: Logging from within your parallel loop with seriously slow it down since you then need synchronization. You not print `blablabla` _before_ the loop?

Comment: As I wrote, the "brute-force" way would be using a mutex. But depending on your actual processing it can cause a synchronzation penalty (performance-wise).

Comment: [exchange](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/exchange) might work for you in this case, with `atomic_bool`.

Comment: I'll explore std::atomic<bool> as @mch and others suggest.

Comment: Or, for this particular problem, [call_once](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) might be even better

Comment: `std::atomic<int> only_first(0);` and `if (only_first.fetch_or(1) == 0)` seems to work: https://godbolt.org/z/6f6xWa3dj

Comment: In the case `omp atomic` is not recognized by MSVC (which uses a quite old OpenMP version), it's perfectly fine to enclose the whole test in a `omp critical` region, as long as the "do something" stuff represent a significant workload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick with OpenMP atomics, try this. It uses a [test and test-and-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Test_and_test-and-set&oldid=1148997643) logic to avoid cache-line bouncing and needless synchronization overhead.

```cpp
int main()
{
    int iteration = 0;

#   pragma omp parallel for
    for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        int own_iteration;
#       pragma omp atomic read relaxed
        own_iteration = iteration;
        if(own_iteration == 0) {
#           pragma omp atomic update relaxed capture
            own_iteration = iteration += 1;
            if(own_iteration == 1)
                std::cout << "blablabla\n";
        }
    }
}
```

You can make the code simpler with C++-11 atomics.

```cpp
#include <atomic>

int main()
{
    std::atomic<bool> first_iteration = true;

#   pragma omp parallel for
    for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        if(first_iteration.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)
                && first_iteration.exchange(false, std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
            std::cout << "blablabla\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Of course "first iteration" doesn't really mean much in fully parallel execution. You might as well check `if(j == 0)` and be done with it.